# Git Branches after SVN Migration

Tags: git, github, git-svn, git-branch

I migrated my group's project from SVN to github using git-svn. The history was preserved correctly, but the SVN branches were committed at the top level directory of master instead of into git-branches. Prior to merge, these branches were in sync with the 'trunk'.

So the github directory structure looks like:

```
trunk/
branches/
        *branch1
        *branch2
        etc.
```

I would like to move each of the sub-folders in the branch folder into its own git branch and then remove them from the master. But I am not sure if I need to create a branch by itself, and then merge the folder in and then delete the folder? Or rebase with the master?

The original command that I used to migrate the repository was:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata --authors-file=users.txt svn://path/to/my/SVN
```

But this still does not get the branches correct. Would anyone be able to help me with this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-s/--stdlayout` option when doing `git svn init` or `clone`, e.g.

```
 git svn clone -s <path to the svn folder containing trunk and branches>
```

this way git-svn will recognize your trunk as master and your svn branches as git branches.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response... the command that I used was:

git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata --authors-file=users.txt svn://hostname/path dest_dir-tmp     

But, it still did not work. I am just hoping at this point to work with what is already in git and just move folders to the branches. Is this possible?

Comment: If you like nice history you might want to make the `git svn clone` import your project properly. Otherwise you might give [git subtree](https://www.mankier.com/1/git-subtree) a try:  `git subtree split --prefix=branches/branch1 -b branch1` seems to be close to what you need, but doesn't seem to be preserving the history.